# squared matrix of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

I am new to graph theory, I am working with DAGs.

I came across this code, that when working with 3 nodes it did:

```
dag2=dag2+(dag %^% 2)
```

When it had 4 nodes:

```
for(i in 2:3)
    dag2=dag2+(dag %^% i)
```

I do understand the code, but I don't know what this means graphically. My question is, what is this doing graphically: what means to square or cube the matrix representation of a graph?

Comment: The $x,y$-entry of the $n$th power is the number of $n$ length paths between the corresponding nodes of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Great! Does this property have a name? How can I search for more information about it?